# CMake can't find OpenSSL Library

Tags: c++, cmake, openssl

I am using CMake on WSL:Ubuntu. I cloned the OpenSSL library from github, and here is my CMakeLists.txt file and the error I get when try to build. What am I missing or doing wrong that won't allow it to be found?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try setting the root directory _prior_ to trying to find the package?

Comment: [Why should i not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Do you have the development packages for OpenSSL installed (with header files and everything) or just the runtime libraries? You need the former.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Post text as *text*, directly in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to update your packages:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev

either you can specify the root directory of openssl:
set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR "/usr/include/openssl") //change filepath as your configs

and find the openssl:
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)

and if it's not solved as expected and you're seeing errors again, please reach me

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked. I did not install libssl-dev in the correct spot, and had the incorrect file path. thank you

Comment: Your welcome, love ya! You can reach me whenever you want at Stackoverflow.